# npm ERR! code 1 during installation of opentelemetryio - Error in hugo-extended postinstall.js

Tags: javascript, open-telemetry

[image]I'm encountering an error while setting up opentelemetryio's development environment (https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry.io)(https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry.io/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.md) (https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry.io/blob/main/package.json)using npm. Here's the output:

npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
... (other deprecation warnings)
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/rafe/Desktop/opentelemetryio/node_modules/hugo-extended
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node postinstall.js

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/rafe/.npm/_logs/2024-03-10T06_00_26_721Z-debug-0.log

System Information:

```
OS: Ubuntu 23.10
npm version: 10.5.0
node version: v20.11.1
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank You in advance.

The error seems to originate during the postinstall.js script execution within the hugo-extended package. I've tried the following troubleshooting steps (if applicable):

```
Cleared npm cache (npm cache clean --force)
Reinstalled dependencies (npm install)
```

I am expecting to setup the development environment of this website https://opentelemetry.io/

The codebase of this website can be found here --> https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry.io

Answer (score 0):

Our production pipeline builds fine under Ubuntu 20.x. I don't have access to a 23.x system, but have you tried only installing and running only `hugo` from `hugo-extended` like this:

```
$ npx -p hugo-extended \hugo version
```

If that fails then the problem is with the [hugo-extended](https://github.com/jakejarvis/hugo-extended) package -- consider [filing an issue](https://github.com/jakejarvis/hugo-extended/issues/new/choose).